# Export CSV file to Hive

Tags: mongodb, hive, hdfs

I have a CSV file which I downloaded from mongo db and would like to export it to hive so that I can query it and analyze it. However, i suppose I need to first export it to HDFS. I have Hive installed on my system. I used the following command:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reg_log (path STRING, ip STRING)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
> LOCATION '/home/nazneen/Desktop/mongodb-linux/bin/reqlog_new_mod.csv'
> STORED AS CSVFILE;
```

This is throwing error. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The STORED AS needs to come before the LOCATION I believe. You can also mount a mongodb collection from hive using https://github.com/alphaHeavy/Hive-mongo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 'STORED AS' clause doesn't support keyword 'CSVFILE', see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL). In your case 'STORED AS TEXTFILE' should be fine.